# Конструктор Класса по умолчанию

Tags: классы, c++

в определении класса я пишу: M_ch(int CH =0); // M_ch-имя класса

в другом файле у меня определяется этот конструктор:

```
M_ch::M_ch(int CH =0) 
{
    for(int i=0; i<A; i++)
        ch[i]=CH;
}
```

и на это выдает ошибку:  M_ch::M_ch: переопределение параметра по умолчанию: параметр 1

если в принимающих значениях функции убираю равенство нулю, то все ок.
но я хочу, что бы у меня этот конструктор был и конструктором по умолчанию.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что я не правильно делаю и как надо определять.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В определении метода не пишите значение по умолчанию, просто

```
M_ch::M_ch(int CH )  {
.....
}
```

Значения по умолчанию пишутся только в объявлении метода, если объявление и определение даются отдельно.